# Put a picture(logo) in UITableView in the bottom of a scrollable View which won't be scrollable

Tags: iphone

I tried everything, with the footer section even I tried to put an non functional Button in the Footer of the UITableView.

But it scolls up and down if there are not so many items to show.

How can I put an Image in the button which won't move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your tableview a bit small and add a UIImageView at the bottom of the super view which contains the tablebview.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but i figured it out myself. I just put an Toolbar at the bottom and putted the logo/image in it and it looks awesome. Thx anyway for the answer

Comment: Then you are free to post it as an answer here and accept it for yourself or accept mine.